# Dialog does not Exist in jQuery list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am finalizing a large project and I am to the UI part and the first thing is I after I get all my scripts rendering in order is click on the link for the dialog box to open and the $('.myDialog').dialog does not work any longer.

I get any error that states that there is no object named dialog.

Now when I am in Dev mode in the scripts i can do a $('#myDialog).dialog and the function dialog is not in the list of items to choose from.

What am i missing?

I am currently using jquery 3.1.0.js

Can someone please shed some light onto this for me.

I even tried this with fiddler from an example from Stackoverflow and the dialog was showing the same error.

It's a rather large amount of code in to body of the dialog so i will not post it all here, the thing to note is that there is no dialog in the list and my error is the object dialog does not exist.

```
 $("#addProj").dialog({
            height: 'auto',
            width: '450',
            resizable: false,
            position: [(document.getXYCenter().x - (450 / 2)),
                       $(e.target).position().top + 25],
            modal: false,
            open: function (e, ui) {

                uiHelper.addModel();
            //.....code moved for readability
```

**Bundles'**

```
Bundle jqueryBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryjs")
             .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
             .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}.js");

         bundles.Add(jqueryBundle);
```

I've also done a View Source and the files have in-deed rendered.

Did something change in the last two years?

Comment: Where does the `dialog` method come from? It's not jQuery, is it in jQuery UI? It certainly [looks like it is](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: `my error is the object dialog does not exist` Sure this is not the error message you get... Next time, provide relevant message error instead of some custom one

Comment: I found the issue i forgot with jquery you have to add the core code the the UI code script. Thank you for helping.